# Use ajax in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

This example of use ajax in Rails http://www.kunce.net/2013/10/ror-dynamic-dropdown-box-with-ajax/
I have it does not work, what am I doing wrong?
The can must be connected gem or is it ustanevshy method that does not work?
I need to get to the divas data that the user has selected in the select without refreshing the page. 
View:

```
<div id="select_div">
    <select name="city_id" id="city_id">
      <option value="0">Lisbon</option>
      <option value="1">Madrid</option>
      <option value="2">Prague</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="result_div">
  <h4>Lisbon is selected</h4>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#city_id').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
           url: "<%= update_text_path %>",
           data: {
               city_name: $("#city_id option:selected").text()
           },
           dataType: "script"
        });
    });
  });
</script>
```

routes.rb:

```
get "static_pages/update_text", as: "update_text"
```

controller static_pages:

```
def update_text
    @city_text = params[:city_name]
end
```

views/static_pages/update_text.js.erb

```
$('#result_div').html("<h4>You have changed the city to: <%= @city_text %></h4>");
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Is anything changing in your browser? What is your server log showing?

Comment: Lanny Bose, Changes in the browser is not
in terminal write: 
[2016-05-30 00:24:37] ERROR bad URI `/%3C%=%20city_id%20%%3E?city_id=2&_=1464557016658'.

Comment: Try removing the quotes around "<%= update_text_path %>". It may be double-quoting it?

Answer (score 0):

The literal value `<%= update_text_path %>` seems to be used as the URL.  Check that your file is named `app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb`, and not `app/views/static_pages/home.html`.  Only the `.erb` file can use ERB markup.

Comment: I use app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb